# Multiple inheritance and singleton design pattern

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, singleton, static-variables

I have the following class hierarchy set up and would like the `print()` function of the non-singleton base object `OtherBase` to be called which in turn calls the `printSymbol()` from one of the child classes, in this case `SingletonChild`. I understand this is a complicated and somewhat unnecessary looking hierarchy and way of doing things but this is an assignment and I am required to do it in this way.

An example of my problem is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object
{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class SingletonBase : public Object
{
private:
    static SingletonBase* theOnlyTrueInstance;
protected:
    SingletonBase()
    {
        if(!theOnlyTrueInstance)
            theOnlyTrueInstance = this;
    }
    virtual ~SingletonBase(){}
public:
    static SingletonBase* instance()
    {
        if (!theOnlyTrueInstance) initInstance();
        return theOnlyTrueInstance;
    }
    void print()
    { cout<<"Singleton"<<endl; }
    static void initInstance()
    { new SingletonBase; }
};

SingletonBase* SingletonBase::theOnlyTrueInstance = 0;

class OtherBase : public Object
{
public:
    virtual string printSymbol() = 0;
    void print()
    { cout<<printSymbol(); }
};

class SingletonChild : public SingletonBase , public OtherBase
{
public:
    string printSymbol()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
    static void initInstance()
    { new SingletonChild; }
};

int main() {
    SingletonChild::initInstance();
    OtherBase* test = (OtherBase*) SingletonChild::instance();
    test->print();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the instance `test` to call the `print` function of the one base class `OtherBase` and not the Singleton base class `SingletonBase`?

I have tried `test->OtherBase::print()`, but this did not work.

Comment: You just want your `test` object to call the `OtherBase`'s `print` method instead of `SingletonBase`'s?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad Yes, thats pretty much it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SingletonChild` is inheriting it's `instance` method from `SingletonBase`, which is returning a pointer to `SingletonBase`.
So calling `SingletonChild::instance();` will get you a `SingletonBase*`, which you can't simply cast to `OtherBase*`

Try casting it to `SingletonChild*` first, then to `OtherBase*`:

```
OtherBase* test = (OtherBase*)((SingletonChild*)SingletonChild::instance());
```

And then call the `print` method simply like this: `test->print();`

See the [code on ideone](http://ideone.com/60NZUW).

**EDIT**:

You can also achieve this like this:

```
SingletonChild* test = (SingletonChild*)SingletonChild::instance();
test->OtherBase::print();
```

See [this method in action](http://ideone.com/fsKimI) too.

Answer (score 3):

@MuhammadAhmad's answer is basically right.  I would like to add that the main issue here is that a C-style cast is allowing you to do something that you really don't want to do.  Because you can't statically cast a `SingletonBase` to an `OtherBase`, the C-style cast is doing a `reinterpret_cast` instead, and calling `print()` on the resulting pointer is undefined behavior.  If you had used a `static_cast`, you would have gotten an error:

```
OtherBase* test = static_cast<OtherBase*>(SingletonChild::instance());
```

> error: invalid static_cast from type ‘SingletonBase*’ to type ‘OtherBase*’

This may have led you to realize you needed to do things a bit differently.  For example, you can use a `dynamic_cast` to cast sideways like this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is casting an object of type SingletonBase* to type `OtherBase*`, which *is not* possible because `SingletonBase` does not derive from `OtherBase`. If you had used `dynamic_cast` rather than old, deprecated C-style cast, you would have recognized this situation rather immediately.

To solve the issue, you need to modify the code as follows:

```
class Object
{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class SingletonBase : public Object
{
private:
    static Object* theOnlyTrueInstance;
protected:
    SingletonBase()
    {
        if(!theOnlyTrueInstance)
            theOnlyTrueInstance = this;
    }
    virtual ~SingletonBase(){}
public:
    static Object* instance()
    {
        if (!theOnlyTrueInstance) initInstance();
        return theOnlyTrueInstance;
    }
    void print()
    { cout<<"Singleton"<<endl; }
    static void initInstance()
    { new SingletonBase; }
};

Object* SingletonBase::theOnlyTrueInstance = 0;

class OtherBase : public Object
{
public:
    virtual string printSymbol() = 0;
    void print()
    { cout<<printSymbol(); }
};

class SingletonChild : public SingletonBase , public OtherBase
{
public:
    string printSymbol()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
    static void initInstance()
    { new SingletonChild; }
};

int main() {
    SingletonChild::initInstance();
    OtherBase* test = dynamic_cast<OtherBase*>(SingletonChild::instance());
    test->print();
    return 0;
}
```

You should avoid C-style casts, as you could end-up manipulating object like something they are not.